# Garbage black text on white screen on a server

Tags: server

I installed ubuntu server on a computer and it seems to work fine, I can ssh into it and everything but I can't understand anything that appears on the screen. It has a white background and instead of normal characters it just shows garbage text.

This is a picture of the screen

[image]

This is a video of the computer starting if that helps http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kw3VKIpqCXw

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Hi, did any of the answers help you?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be some problem with the graphics driver used by the kernel. Try to boot with the nomodeset kernel parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to edit your grub - /etc/defaults/grub file

> Blockquote

uncommented the "GRUB_GFXMODE" line

For my monitor which is 1280x1024 I made the line read:

> GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024

You should be able to do this by selecting recovery mode at boot time (if you do not get grub boot options hold the 'shift' key during boot.

If that does not work then edit the grub options at boot time be pressing 'e' before selecting your boot option and try adding vga=xxx (see the following link for the mode to pick: http://pierre.baudu.in/other/grub.vga.modes.html )

I hope that helps.